# react forms - how can I style the Choice element from the rocketseat/unform library?

Tags: reactjs, forms

I'm using the rocketseat form to create a search form but I'm not able to style some elements such as the Choice element and the Check element

below the form code:

```
return (
    <Container>
      <div className="title">Pesquisar aulas</div>
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit} ref={formRef}>
        <div className="input-box">
          <span>Ano Letivo:</span>
          {edicoes[0] && (
            <Input
              name="anoLetivo1"
              type="text"
              placeholder="ano letivo"
              readOnly
              value={edicoes[0].ano_lectivo}
            />
          )}
        </div>
        <div className="input-box">
          <span>Unidade Curricular:</span>
          <Select
            name="unidadeCurricular1"
            options={optionsDisciplinas}
            placeholder="Nenhum selecionado"
          />
        </div>

        <div className="input-box">
          <span>Curso:</span>
          <Choice name="curso1" options={optionsCursos} multiple />
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Pesquisar</button>
      </Form>
  </Container>
  );
```

I'm using styled-components to style the other elements like the Input element and the Select element

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

export const Container = styled.div`
  form {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-top: 30px;

    select {
      background: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      border: 0;
      border-radius: 4px;
      height: 34px;
      padding: 0 15px;
      color: #000;
      margin: 0 0 10px;

      &::placeholder {
        color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
      }
    }

    input {
      background: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      border: 0;
      border-radius: 4px;
      height: 34px;
      padding: 0 15px;
      color: #000;
      margin: 0 0 10px;

      &::placeholder {
        color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
      }
    }
`;
```

But when I try to do the same with the Choice element the styling doesn't work it doesn't recognize the Choice as an element unlike what happens with the Input and Select elements that work perfectly

Below is a screenshot of my form, I want to be able to style the input courses and align the "checkBox" with its respective label using flexBox

[image]